# Is there a way to define function-dictionaries in android/Java like in python?

Tags: java, android, python, dictionary

In python it is possible to create a dictionary of functions (`foo,bar`) and call them by accessing the dictionaries element:

```
d = {'a':foo, 'b':bar}
d[val]()
```

In this example if `var='a'` the function `foo` is called, and if `var='b'` the function `bar` is called (other choices lead to errors).

Can I do something like that in android/Java?

Comment: Is your question how to put functions inside an `HashMap`? Or whether is there a syntax like python's to build an `HashMap`?

Comment: Is there a way I can achieve something like I wrote in python in Java in a similar elegant way?

Answer (score 1):

This is easy in Python because methods are [First-Class Citizens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function).  Whereas in Java, they are not.

In Java 8 -however- you can create a `Map` (in this case a `HashMap`) of `Runnable`

```
Map<Character, Runnable> methods= new HashMap<>();
methods.put('help', () -> System.out.println("Help"));
```

Then run it

```
methods.get('help').run();
```

You can do it with reflection also but the code looks very much like this.

Comment: Well, `Runnable` exists since JDK 1, and nothing prevents you from implementing the interface as `RunFoo` and `RunBar`... that's the "command pattern" from the GoF. Java 8 only provides lambda functions that let you avoid writing an entire `Runnable` implementation to insert a value in that dictionary.

Comment: Yes but at that point it starts to get even more un-pythonic and I'm thinking the OP is looking for something as pythonic as possible

Comment: Yes, I am looking form something pythonic. I could do it with if statements, but I consider this bad programming style.

Comment: I also require the use if arguments. I will do it with if statements, whatever...

Comment: I tried `LOG_FOO.put('v', () -> this.v);` resulting in an error 'illegal start of expression'

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;

class HashMethod {
    public void foo() {
        System.out.println("foo");
    }

    public void bar() {
        System.out.println("bar");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalAccessException {
        HashMethod obj = new HashMethod();
        Map<Character, java.lang.reflect.Method> methods = new HashMap<Character, java.lang.reflect.Method>();
        try {
            Character val = 'a';
            java.lang.reflect.Method method = obj.getClass().getMethod("foo");
            methods.put(val, method);
            Character val2 = 'b';
            java.lang.reflect.Method method2 = obj.getClass().getMethod("bar");
            methods.put(val2, method2);
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            System.out.print("exc1" + e.toString());
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            System.out.print("exc2" + e.toString());
        }
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        Character val = s.next().charAt(0);
        try {
            java.lang.reflect.Method methodToRun = ((java.lang.reflect.Method) methods.get(val));
            methodToRun.invoke(obj, null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.print("invalid input");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I know I can do it this way. But this is a very ugly way. I was hoping for a more elegant way to do this, like in python ...

Comment: This doesn't answer the question... the code cannot be made dynamic (e.g. add/remove a possible action at runtime), also having like hundreds/thousands actions is not really possible for a sane code base.

Answer (score -1):

In Java Dictionaries we will Call it as HashTable / HashMap.

Please have a look at this Classes. 
https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Hashtable.html

Example of HashTable:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_hashtable_class.htm

https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/HashMap.html

Hope this will helps you :)

Comment: What is the type of a function then?

Comment: HashTable or Hashmap classes you have to use. Please check the above given example link